# IDLE keeps restarting when running the arcpy.Clip_management geoprocess

Tags: arcpy, idle

I am trying to run an IDW on some precipitation points, but when I try to clip the IDW raster to a polygon boundary, it keeps restarting the IDLE shell. This happens when I run it in the shell, and as a complete script. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\\someWorkspace"
env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3d")

#Declare local variable, the points to be interpolated
points = "PrecipKansas2014"

#Making the points to be interpolated a feature layer, for processing in IDLE
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "points_lyr")

#IDW
arcpy.Idw_3d("points_lyr", "RASTERVALU", "precipNew")

#Clip IDW raster to the polygon state boundary
arcpy.Clip_management("precipNew", "KansasBoundary", "idwClip")
```

This is as far as I get, as the whole program restarts. The next step would be to `arcpy.ExtractByMask()` to get data from a specified region, but that will come later.

Using ArcGIS version 10.7.1, no patches applied.

Comment: Is your 'c:\\someWorkspace' actually an Esri GRID workspace and not just a folder? I assume you've changed the path *but* that could be a potential cause, there are some very stringent rules to ArcINFO workspaces which you may be contravening inadvertently. Try changing "idwClip" to "idwClip.tif" and see if that helps. In my opinion the shell window of IDLE has its own set of issues, you could try copy/pasting your code into an ArcCatalog python window and see if that helps. I use PyWin32 IDE shell which I've found isn't as buggy as IDLE.

Comment: Are you saying that you are running your script from IDLE's Python Script window, and that stays open while IDLE's Python Shell window also stays open but restarts the script without you intervening?

Comment: @Michael Stimson Thanks, that probably makes the most sense. I tried your suggestion with the "idwClip.tif", and it does the same thing. I might have to try the PythonWin option.

Comment: @PolyGeo when I save the script and press "F5" to run it, the Python shell opens, and after about a minute, I get the "RESTART: Shell" option. Meaning that it has terminated/crashed and restarted. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it worked much better to use the `ExtractByMask` option instead of the `arcpy.Clip_management` process. The corrected code is as follows:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#Must use the arcpy.sa for this option#
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:\\workspace"
env.overwriteOutput = True

points = "PrecipKansas2014"

#Check out extensions:
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial") and arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3d")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "points_lyr")
arcpy.Idw_3d("points_lyr", "RASTERVALU", "precipNew")
ExtractBymask("precipNew", "KansasBoundary)

#Check in extensions:
arcpy.CheckInExtension("3d") and arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```